# why my Ios App is killed by OS in background mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift4, swift5

hi i have an iOS app that runs perfectly in  when i run it through Xcode on my iPhone.when i press the home button and lock the screen, the app keeps recording the data.after 1 or 2 hours when i unlock screen it is still recording data and works perfectly.but when i stop the app , unplug my phone and run the installed app directly through app icon on my iPhone it is killed by the os after a few seconds in lock screen.i have already asked similar question but couldn't find any help.if someone could download the source code and have a look at it it will be very nice of him/her.Thank you

Comment: Since it is attached to the debugger, it will never get killed.

Comment: ahan .i get it know.

Answer (score 1):

> why my Ios App is killed by OS in background mode?

The OS won't allow apps to run for long periods in the background in order to save power. There are exceptions — you can tell the OS that your app needs to run in the background for one of [several reasons](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) such as playing music in the background. There are also some facilities for waking up your app in the background to do some processing -- for example, your app can be notified when the location changes.

Comment: thanks for your answer sir...can you tell me how can i tell the os that my app needs more time to keep calculating the location and marking the map.

Comment: Why would you need to mark a map if the app is in the background?

Comment: the app keeps recording the user's movement and shows all the location he went through.users simply start the recording button and then they lock the screen .after a few hours they unlock the device and see the whole path they traveled.

Comment: @SheheryarAhmed You don’t need to update the map until the user actually wakes the phone. Instead, use [Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1) to monitor location changes — your app can be notified even when not running. All it needs to do is add the new location to its data. Redraw the map when the app comes to the foreground again.

Comment: i have done the same thing still when i lock lock screen the app is killed by os. in plist i have added AlwaysAndWhenInUseAuthorization. and i have set  locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization().what can be issue now?

Comment: Read the section I linked to, on region monitoring: *If a region boundary is crossed while an app isn’t running, that app is relaunched into the background to handle the event...*

Comment: my app keeps relaunching for no reason every time i unlock my device